# linking postscript pdfmark DST with latex hypertarget/bookmark

Tags: latex, bookmarks, postscript, pdflatex, hyperref

```
%!PS
/Helvetica findfont 20 scalefont setfont
20 dup moveto (Comparator) show newpath
[ /Rect [ 20 dup moveto (Comparator)  false charpath pathbbox newpath ] 
/DST /Color [.7 0 0] %use Page 2 to make this work temporary
/Subtype /Link 
/ANN  pdfmark
showpage
```

For the above postscript, I donot know the destination page number until the full pdf is generated.The description for *Comparator* is found at the end of pdf in a description table.I tried to link it via Latex with \hypertarget but didn't work. *Comparator* in pdf can exists more than once and they should be be linked to my description table at the end. Which way is best to complete my task? please advise.

Comment: I recognize parts of it ;-) I thought you translate ps->pdf, but normally pages would not change any more once you have the postscript?

Comment: Hello again  :) . I am translating PS to Latex then to PDF . I should some how link the DST in pdfmark with the data in the description table.

Comment: I think you have the choice to link to the page number, or a link target on that page - the page number is fix once you have the postscript, isn't it?

Comment: No I don't have the page number until the full pdf is generated. I should create a bookmark for each item in description table then link it with the pdfmark in postscript. But I am not successful in doing this

Comment: But you can generate the pdf once ahead without your links first and the page numbers will be exactly the same as when you insert your links and then generate a pdf again - adding the links can't modify the page numbers.  Or how could they?

Comment: This is more complicated thing to do.Already my pdf is very large and generating it twice is going to increase the time. Also I would like to somehow make this generic.I have a TT file where I am using hypertarget{parametr_name} then \input{parametr file path} . At the same time in my PS file I am using above script (posted) in generic way /DST parametr_name which doesn't work at the moment but I want to make it work.

Comment: I see. But then, why don't you use hyperref to let it generate the link instead of trying yourself? - Still do not understand the question completely - you are asking about the right value for the /DST (destination)? That will point to the place where you specified the hypertarget? You still could generate one test pdf file using a test tex file where you let the hyperref package build the link and then you inspect the pdf and see what it inserts into /DST, and then do the same for all positions yourself. - if it inserts the pagenumber explicitly then you're probably lost...

Comment: Hello Stefan , hyperref and hypertarget for some reason did not get linked with my pdfmark DST but the good news is when I used postscript code inside latex (using special tag ) to specify my DST parametr, linked the target perfectly :)  . Thanks for your kind discussion .